# cant receive product list bigcommerce api

Tags: php, laravel, bigcommerce

I can't receive product list. I got error:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

on `var_dump` products got `bool(false)`

This is my code:

```
namespace StoreAPI;
use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce_Api;

class Bigcommerce implements StoreApiInterface {

// For Connecting
public function Connect($data )
{

    Bigcommerce_Api::configure(array(
        'store_url' => 'https://store-t8knnf.mybigcommerce.com/dav',
        'username' => 'name@gmail.com',
        'api_key' => 'key'
    ));

    Bigcommerce_Api::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
    Bigcommerce_Api::verifyPeer(false);

    $products = Bigcommerce_Api::getProducts();

    foreach($products as $product) {
        echo $product->name;
        echo $product->price;
    }
    die('asd');
}
```

I'm working with Laravel 4.

Comment: It seems that result $products = Bigcommerce_Api::getProducts(); is false. What if you add check if (!$products) { Bigcommerce_api::getLastError(); print_r($error); } ?

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [status] => 401 [message] => The specified credentials were invalid. ) )

Comment: Try changing the url to "https://store-t8knnf.mybigcommerce.com/" if your credentials are ok.

Comment: problem solved. it was bad with username and key. thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

modify your code:

```
    Bigcommerce::configure([
        'client_id' => 'client_id',
        'auth_token' => 'your token',
        'store_hash' => 'hash'
    ]);
```

Comment: https://github.com/digitaldevelopers/bigcommerce-api-php